# using a getter and setter function viable for account?

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

I am doing a program that involve creating an account, I need to create so that it will scan specific data to carry out an assigned command. is the getter and setter function suitable for it?

```
public class Account {

    //data
    private int userId;
    private String password;
    private char type;

    public Account(int userId, String password, char type) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.password = password;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public char getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(char type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    //methods
    public boolean verifyLogin(int usrid , String pass)
    {
      if((usrid == userId) & (pass == password)){
          return true;
      }  
      else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it wouldn't be logic to change the userId, so you should remove the setUserId, in your verifyLogin, you should compare pass using the equals method instead of the == operator. As for your question, could you please describe more clearly exactly what you are asking?

Comment: In your implementation getter and setter do absolutely nothing. I do not know what the obsession is for universities to ask encapsulation for all methods. If you would do a check for example, if password matches old password, then do not allow to set it, it makes sense. Otherwise, what is the point of encapsulating it, if you could use direct field access?

Comment: Why do you think it won't be suitable ?

Comment: You should use && instead of & in verifyLogin method.

Comment: well it is needed to put those getter and setters for some of the key methods, but you are right in the sense that I shouldent apply encapsulation to all of my methods. i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your getters and setters look fine for accessing the data of this class.

Something you need to be very careful with is how you check if the password is correct.

In your implementation you use `pass == password` for comparing two strings. This is NOT correct and you should rather use `pass.equals(password)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, but you need to rethink if Setters for some values are necessary. In example it is not very common use case that UserID will change somehow. If you want to keep it persistant, setter is not necessary. Set it once in constructor.

Additionally you can take a look on the [Lombok Project](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) and @Getter & @Setter annotation. It will minimalize your code to 3 lines.